# d3 updated json loads but doesn't access new data

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm an amateur. Please be gentle.

Experience I'm trying to build: Draw a chart. Remove SVG. Load new data. Draw a chart.

There will be a dozen or so json files, all identically structured. I'm using two for now.

I have everything happening up to updating and accessing the second json but then it fails to draw the new x axis because it

> 'cannot read property 'date' of undefined'

It read the date the first time around. it hangs up on .tickValues, where i access first, middle and last date values in json...:

```
.call(d3.axisBottom(x)
    .tickValues([perf[start].date, perf[mid].date, perf[perflength-1].date])
    .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%m-%d-%y")))
    //...
```

where these are the variables I'm feeding there:

```
var perf = json.performance
var perflength = json.performance.length
var mid = perflength/2
var start = 0

perf.forEach(function(d) {
  d.date = parseTime(d.date);
});
```

though i suspect if i could get by there it would continue to throw errors.
json is structured like this:

```
{
  "performance" : [
    {
      "date": "1-27-15",
      "company": 0,
      "index": 0
    },
    {
      "date": "1-28-15",
      "company": 5.7,
      "index": -0.9
    }, 
    //...
  ]
}
```

So my question is what step am I missing that makes json.performance undefined the second time around?

This is my first question so I don't know if I should post my whole script file or not. Maybe this can be answered from the information here. I'll add it if you think it would help.

Comment: It'd be perfect if you could add a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/) (or any other editor) where in this error could be reproduced. `date of undefined` suggests that it's not finding the appropriate data (in the second JSON) - an easy fix.

Comment: Thank you @Shashank. I've created a fiddle and hosted the two json with myjson but I think I'm missing a step in getting the fiddle to access those. The fiddle is [link](https://jsfiddle.net/sberinato/57hf39hd/8/)here

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I'll get back to you with a fix.

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't get back with an answer as I got busy with my own work. Anyway, glad that the issue has been fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using divisor `/` to calculate `mid` variable, which you later use in the `tickValues`. The `/` operator doesn't guarantee you an integer value (ex.: 7/2 = 3.5), so it may fail to access `perf` array and then it raises the error you have posted, as you cannot access the `date` property of an undefined value.

So, parse your division result to an integer (`parseInt()`) or round it (`Math.round`) to solve your problem.

Comment: Of course. Because some of my datasets will not have an even number of days in the data. Going to try this. Thank you. Do you have a recommendation between (parseInt()) or (Math.round) ? // I tried this and it threw the same error in the same place, unfortunately. Will continue to fiddle.

Comment: Typo on my part. This worked. It plotted the next dataset, albeit without transitions but I'll figure that out. Thank you very much. For my first experience here you and @Shashank were great.

Comment: Pleased to help you. Actually `Math.round()` would be the correct as `parseInt()` parses a string to an integer while `Math.round()` works with numbers as it is in your case.